# Hiding overflow on a column with gutters

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to set up a grid of thumbnails for blog posts using Bootstrap 4.

The size of the columns are `col-md-6`. Inside each of the columns is an anchor with a background photo, and a black -> transparent gradient overlay.

It all works fine, however, the gradient overlay is expanding past the width of the container, as you can see from the image below.

[image: Overflowing]
**Markup:**

```
<div class="container homeSection">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 dualBlogCallout">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="img-holder border-radius-15">
          <div class="dualGradient"></div>
          <img src="assets/img/beachPlaceholder.png" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="Blog Alt"/>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 dualBlogCallout">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="img-holder border-radius-15">
          <div class="dualGradient"></div>
          <img src="assets/img/beachPlaceholder.png" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="Blog Alt"/>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dualBlogCallout{
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
.dualBlogCallout a{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dualGradient{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1));
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**Here is my desired result:**

[image: desired]

How can I get the absolutely positioned gradient to just remain within anchor with no overflow, and without using bootstrap 4 `no-gutter` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a rule in your css:

```
.img-holder { position: relative; }
```

I think your issue is that `.dualGradient` is positioned absolutely, but the nearest parent that has a position set is the `.dualBlogCallout`.

By default, anything that has `position: absolute` will traverse up the markup to find the nearest element that has a position explicitly set.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfect, and your explanation made sense.

Comment: @Joe You're welcome! Parent positioning has bitten me more times than I care to admit :)

Answer (score 0):

`position: relative;` is missing on your `img-holder` class. Here is a solution displaying your code.

Note: I added the border radius class because that was not included in the original post

```css
.img-holder {
  position: relative;
}
.dualBlogCallout{
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
.dualBlogCallout a{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dualGradient{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1));
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.border-radius-15 {
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container homeSection">
  <br><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 dualBlogCallout">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="img-holder border-radius-15">
          <div class="dualGradient"></div>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="Blog Alt"/>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 dualBlogCallout">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="img-holder border-radius-15">
          <div class="dualGradient"></div>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="Blog Alt"/>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```